# can flash websites be automated without mouse cursor interaction using sikuli

Tags: flash, sikuli

I am currently working on a flash website where I have to use sikuli to automate the testNG testcase. I am working in some other tabs also simultaneously while executing  the test case,because of which I am  finding an issue, since sikuli needs mouse cursor interaction for clicking on the image it does not click on the image whereas it remains on the same page. Can anyone suggest me if there is a way through which images can be clicked without mouse interaction, so that test case does not fail?

Comment: Sikuli, when it initiates the screen object takes the control of **Mouse & Keyboard** to interact with controls. In your case when you are opening new tab , **You** are taking control. So one option would have been using Keyboard events if not mouse. But for that also, sikuli needs the app to open on screen and not somewhere running in background or tab.

Comment: So there is no way through which this can be avoided? it will necessarily take control of mouse

Comment: As far as I know, no you can not have application running off the screen when using Sikuli.